# Make code snippets results window vertically resizable

Tags: feature-request, stack-snippets

Now that we have [stack snippets](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/), it would be cool if the results window could be resized the same way we can resize the edit textarea for asking/answering questions, e.g. with a grippie.

[Here is an example post that would greatly benefit from being able to resize the results box.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269844/1768232)

And another:

[image: Simon Says: Expand Me!!]

Comment: both vertical and horizontal would be nice

Comment: Anything so we could easily refer back to the question, grab code from it to include, etc. Opening a separate tab to do it is a pain.

Comment: Similar request [@MSO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271776/2333214)

Comment: Time for @rene to make another userscript.

Answer (score -1):

You can wrap your snippet contents in a resizeable div as a workaround.  Here's a demo:

```css
.resizeable {
  resize: horizontal;
  overflow: scroll;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 95vh;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  min-width: 120px;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}

img {
  float: right;
  margin: 10px;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="resizeable"> <img src="https://www.preventivevet.com/hs-fs/hubfs/Cat-Scratching-Resize.jpg" />
  <span>"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"</span>

  <span>"At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat."</span></div>
```

Comment: This is not really a workaround because the wrapping container is still fixed size.

Comment: @durron597 - I understand what you mean - was just a way to see responsive elements in action since there's no other convenient way to resize the snippet window size at all.  You can't make it bigger but you can squash it which is better than nothing.

Comment: A fair point but it doesn't actually answer the problem I am calling out here. You are answering a different (though equally valid) question.